# JS библиотека для интерактивных графиков с хорошей производительностью

Tags: javascript, библиотеки

Есть данные в .csv формате (порядка 10к записей или больше), необходимо их отобразить в графиках. Кром того, графики должны быть интерактивными, иметь всякие контроллеры и фильтры. 
Сейчас я использую google charts, но, к моему удивлению, у него появляются проблемы с производительностью на таких данных. Начинаются лаги при попытке взаимодействовать с графиком и т.д.

Тащемта, мне нужно:

1. JS библиотека для отрисовки графиков
2. С хорошей производительностью.
3. С вот [такими](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls) штуками или чем-то подобным. А точнее аналогами *CategoryFilter* и *ChartRangeFilter*.
4. Бесплатная

Что можете посоветовать? Самих библиотек гуглится сходу очень много, но есть ли среди них то, что мне нужно?

Answer (score 1):

Я порекомендовал бы вам использовать [**Google Charts**](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery) и дальше, который содержит большое количество различных вариаций графиков.

Попробуйте переводить `csv` в массив, когда я делал подобные графики на 30К записей, никаких "провисаний" не возникало.

Для перевода `csv` в массив вы можете использовать [`jquery-csv library`](https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv). Далее все пропускается через `google.visualization.arrayToDataTable()` (**[Пример](http://evanplaice.github.io/jquery-csv/examples/google-visualization.html)**).

---

Пример инициализации графика с использованием `csv`:

```
// load the visualization library from Google and set a listener
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

// this has to be a global function
function drawChart() {
   // grab the CSV
   $.get("example.csv", function(csvString) {
      // transform the CSV string into a 2-dimensional array
      var arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(csvString, {onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar});

      // this new DataTable object holds all the data
      var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);

      // this view can select a subset of the data at a time
      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      view.setColumns([0,1]);

     // set chart options
     var options = {
        title: "A Chart from a CSV!",
        hAxis: {title: data.getColumnLabel(0), minValue: data.getColumnRange(0).min, maxValue: data.getColumnRange(0).max},
        vAxis: {title: data.getColumnLabel(1), minValue: data.getColumnRange(1).min, maxValue: data.getColumnRange(1).max},
        legend: 'none'
     };

     // create the chart object and draw it
     var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
     chart.draw(view, options);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать [d3](https://d3js.org/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
  <title>DOM Manipulation</title>
</head>

<style>
  body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  #wrapper {
    height: 220px;
  }
  .person {
    height: 20px;
    position: relative;
  }
  .person .label {
    width: 90px;
    text-align: right;
  }
  .person .bar {
    height: 19px;
    background-color: steelblue;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
  }
  .person div {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .data-view {
    padding: 10px;
    color: #777;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 700px;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <div id="wrapper">
  </div>

  <div class="menu">
    <button onClick="updateScores();">Update scores</button>
    <button onClick="addPerson();">Add person</button>
    <button onClick="removePerson();">Remove person</button>
  </div>

  <!-- <div class="data-view"></div> -->

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.2/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var names = ['Andy', 'Beth', 'Craig', 'Diane', 'Evelyn', 'Fred', 'Georgia', 'Harry', 'Isabel', 'John'];
    var myData = [];
    var barWidth = 400;
    var barScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 100]).range([0, barWidth]);

    function randomInteger(n) {
      return Math.floor(10 * Math.random());
    }

    function initialiseData() {
      myData = [{
        "name": "Andy",
        "score": 37
      }, {
        "name": "Beth",
        "score": 39
      }, {
        "name": "Craig",
        "score": 31
      }, {
        "name": "Diane",
        "score": 35
      }, {
        "name": "Evelyn",
        "score": 38
      }];
    }

    function updateBars(data) {
      var u = d3.select('#wrapper')
        .selectAll('.person')
        .data(data, function(d) {
          return d.name;
        });

      var entering = u.enter()
        .append('div')
        .classed('person', true);

      entering.append('div')
        .classed('label', true)
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.name;
        });

      entering.append('div')
        .classed('bar', true);

      entering
        .merge(u)
        .select('.bar')
        .transition()
        .style('width', function(d) {
          return barScale(d.score) + 'px';
        });

      u.exit().remove();
    }

    function addPerson() {
      if (myData.length === 10)
        return;

      myData.push({
        name: names[myData.length],
        score: 30 + randomInteger(70)
      });

      update(myData);
    }

    function removePerson() {
      if (myData.length === 0)
        return;

      myData.pop();

      update(myData);
    }

    function updateScores() {
      for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
        myData[i].score = 30 + randomInteger(70);
      }

      update(myData);
    }

    function updateDataView() {
      d3.select('.data-view').text('Array: ' + JSON.stringify(myData));
    }

    function update() {
      updateBars(myData);
      updateDataView(myData);
    }

    initialiseData();
    update(myData);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

[Больше примеров графиков](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Gallery)